# Materialized View

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, pivot, materialized-views

I want to create materialized view using a sales table.

```
--CREATE TABLE SALES_DATA (
--  Product varchar2(255) default NULL,
--  Date1 varchar2(255),
--  Sale varchar2(50) default NULL,
--  ID number default NULL
--);
```

this my sales table.
sample data for sales table ,

```
INSERT INTO SALES_DATA (Product,Date1,Sale,ID) VALUES ('Premarin','1977',22385,1);
INSERT INTO SALES_DATA (Product,Date1,Sale,ID) VALUES ('Bystolic','1985',23884,2);
INSERT INTO SALES_DATA (Product,Date1,Sale,ID) VALUES ('Hydrocodone/APAP','1955',30428,3);
```

Then I want to create materialized view and get below output ,

[image]

Comment: Creating a materialized view is very simple. The syntax is `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEWS MY_VEW_NAME AS ...`, replacing `...` with a `SELECT` statement to create the view from. However, it looks you are really wanting someone to write the `SELECT` statement for you, which is not what stack overflow is for. You need to try to solve the problem yourself first, then if you get stuck on a specific problem, ask for help on here. To get started, it looks you want to use `PIVOT` functions to create a pivot table: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation:

```
create materialized view mymview as 
select product,
    sum(case when date1 = 2016 then sale else 0 end) as sales_2016,
    sum(case when date1 = 2017 then sale else 0 end) as sales_2017,
    sum(case when date1 = 2018 then sale else 0 end) as sales_2018
    ...
from sales_data
group by product
```

Note: your sample schema does not uses the correct datatypes. `date1` is a year, so it should be a number (or better yet, a `date`) instead of a string. `sale` is an amount, so it should be a `number`, not a string. If you really have those strings, then you need to adapt the conditional expressions, like:

```
    sum(case when date1 = '2016' then to_number(sale) else 0 end) as sales_2016
```

Comment: This is about the materialized view and I want to know how to create those column names, Please ignore data types here. and years are dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You cannot create dynamic names in a materialized view or other view.  The best that you can do is to set up a job that periodically checks if new "columns" appear.  If so, then the job would delete the current materialized view and add a new one.